# `cloud_firestore` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2

Tags: flutter, dart

When ever i run `flutter pub get`
this error comes.
it says about migration but i have no idea on this

[image]

this is my pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 
  # FIREBASE Packages Section
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0 
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0   
  cloud_firestore: 2.5.4 #
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0 
  firebase_storage: ^10.1.0 
  google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.0 

  in_app_purchase: 0.5.2 
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.1 
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1  
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2 
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2 
  scoped_model: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0 
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4 
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1 
  url_launcher: ^6.0.15 
  geolocator: ^7.7.1 
  geocoding: ^2.0.1 
  shimmer: ^2.0.0 
  timeago: ^3.1.0 
  share: ^2.0.4 
  flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker: ^3.0.0
  place_picker: 
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/ajbcoder/locationpicker
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

my current flutter version

```
Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision 135454af32 (2 weeks ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

How can this be fixed to successfully run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to open a very old version of the app. The Flutter Android binding is changed a log since the old versions.
I just faced this issue few days ago.

You have to change some lines in **AndroidManifest.xml** & **MainActivity**.
Or if you don't have very big native implementation in place you can try deleting the `android` folder and run `flutter create .` command to create a fresh android project supporting flutter.
I suggest making a copy of existing android folder to someplace so if you miss some native implementation you can get if from there.

For manual changes there are mainly three things to change.

1. Change name tag in AndroidManifest.xml to following

```
       android:name="${applicationName}"
```

2. Add this code inside the `<application></application>` like this.

```
   <application
     // application props
     >
     // other items
     <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
   </appplication>
```

3. Change you MainActivity file. If its in kotlin you can use this

```
package <your.package.name>'

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

There is also some steps to migrate to AndroidX on the url which is visible in your console output image. But if you recreating the android folder then this won't be required.

Keep in mind that your packages in `pubspec.yaml` also very old & you have to change those packages and code supporting new versions of those packages. For example Firebase integration now needs Firebase CLI to be installed on the system. I tried to implement Firebase with older way but its not supported any more.

Comment: Thnx, I will check that out